# postgresql group by yearweek from date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails date column and would like to group by the yearweek

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

instead of actual weeks.

What is the best way to extract the yearweek?

Currently doing:

`GROUP BY date_part('week', the_actual_date_column)::integer`

Comment: What is the difference between yearweek and actual weeks?

Comment: one returns an integer and other returns a date?

Answer (score 0):

`'week'` shouldnt have single quotes.

according to [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 7
```